# Retrieve all Products from a category via SOAP API v2 WS-I

Tags: magento-1.9, api

I would like to know how to retrieve products that belong to a specific category in Magento SOAP API V2, with WS-I compliance and also without.

Here's what I've tried in WS-I compliance mode:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://foobar.local/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');

$sessionId = $proxy->login(array(
    'username' => 'foo',
    'apiKey' => 'bar'
));

$filters = array( 'complex_filter' =>
    array(
        array(
            'key' => 'category_ids',
            'value' => array( 'key' => 'like', 'value' => '%1%' )
        )
    )
);

$result = $proxy->catalogProductList(array('sessionId' => $sessionId->result, 'filters' => $filters));

var_dump($result->result);
```

I can use the complex filter to successfully filter by `product_id` however this fails to work for category_ids as it has another nested level. How can I retrieve products via the Magento API for a certain category ID? Should I be using `catalog_category.assignedProducts`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic due to inactivity from the OP.

Comment: Are you kidding me? Not a specific coding question about the Magento e-Commerce platform?

Comment: People vote blindly in efforts to rack up points. I've raised this but haven't gotten much of a response. Voting to re-open.

Comment: I would like to hear from the users including @AnnaVölkl that flagged this question, on how my question "does not appear to be about the Magento e-Commerce platform" and how it does not fit within the scope defined.

Comment: @FrancisKim there is a limited inventory of reasons why questions can be put on hold. As Anna stated your question is on hold because it appears you failed to follow up on the first comment on Dec 9. However, I think what was missed was your follow-up edit on Dec 10 which I think addresses the comment. Reopening.

Comment: benmarks is right, I voted because i thought it was outdated and really missed the edit above. Your question was updated, that's good! Sorry for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already noted in your question, the preferred way of retrieving products which belong to a specific category is `catalogCategoryAssignedProducts` for SOAPv2 ([see documentation here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.assignedProducts.html)).

`catalogProductList` is a way of retrieving products by attributes.

Please note that `catalogCategoryAssignedProducts` fetches only products from *one* specific category and not multiple ones.

The SOAP calls according to documentation are:

SOAPv2:

```
$result = $proxy->catalogCategoryAssignedProducts($sessionId, '4');
```

SOAPv2 WS-I:

```
$result = $proxy->catalogCategoryAssignedProducts((object)array('sessionId' => $sessionId->result, 'categoryId' => '4'));
```